# Why is my big commerce curl API create option code failing

Tags: php, curl, bigcommerce

I am using the Bigcommerce curl community library PHP-cURL-lib-for-Bigcommerce-API. I have done many POST operations with it and had no problems. When I try to create a option like this:

```
$arrOptionImp["display_name"] = "Flavor";
$arrOptionImp["type"] = "cs";
$arrOptionImp["name"] = "Zuk-EndTrt Flavor";

try
{
  $arrOptionResult = $objBigCom->post("/options", $arrOptionImp);
  echo "Option Result<br />";
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($arrOptionResult);
  echo "</pre>";
}
  catch(Exception $e)
{
  echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
```

Big commerce returns:

```
Array
(
    [type] => POST
    [url] => https://www.myWebsite.com/api/v2/options/
    [payload] => {"display_name":"Flavor","type":"cs","name":"Zuk-EndTrt Flavor"}
)
```

It should return something like this:
json sample from developer dot bigcommerce dot com

```
{
  "id": 10,
  "name": "Color",
  "type": "CS",
  "values": {
    "url": "https://store-bwvr466 dot mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/options/10/values.json",
    "resource": "/options/10/values"
  },
  "display_name": "Color"
}
```

Anybody have a clue why I am not getting the result with the option Id?

Comment: Ok I think I figured it out. The "type" must be capitalized Should have been "CS" not "cs"

Answer (score 1):

Per your comment, try:

```
$arrOptionImp["display_name"] = "Flavor";
$arrOptionImp["type"] = "CS";
$arrOptionImp["name"] = "Zuk-EndTrt Flavor";

try
{
  $arrOptionResult = $objBigCom->post("/options", $arrOptionImp);
  echo "Option Result<br />";
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($arrOptionResult);
  echo "</pre>";
}
  catch(Exception $e)
{
  echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
```